# jQuery + mobile devices: how do I scroll up and down? (iOS: iPad)

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios, ipad

This is the library I'm using: http://www.netcu.de/jquery-touchwipe-iphone-ipad-library
This is the code I have:

```
                $j("#section-content").touchwipe({
                     wipeLeft: function() {$j('#next-page').trigger('click'); },
                     wipeRight: function() { $j('#prev-page').trigger('click');  },
                     wipeUp: function() { alert("up"); },
                     wipeDown: function() { alert("down"); },
                     min_move_x: 20,
                     min_move_y: 20,
                     preventDefaultEvents: true
                });
```

now, wipeUp and wipeDown appear to not work (I don't see any alerts on the virtual iPad on my mac).
The real problem is that when I have an object that can be wiped left and right, it prevents up down wiping (essential for scrolling long pages).

So how do I do I re-enable scrolling via wipe up / wipe down? Are there better jquery libraries that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that script you're using, comment out this line:

```
     function onTouchMove(e) {
         if(config.preventDefaultEvents) {
             // e.preventDefault();
         }
```

(the prevent default line)

it prevents the mobile browser from doin' it's thang.

Comment: No need to change the script, just set `preventDefaultEvents: false` in your script.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try using the following in your code

```
$("#section-content").touchwipe({
      preventDefaultEvents: false,
      wipeLeft: function() {
      $("#section-content").cycle("next");
      $("#section-content").cycle("pause");
      return false;
    },
    wipeRight: function() {
    $("#section-content").cycle("prev");
    $("#section-content").cycle("pause");
    return false;
    }
    });
```

This is probably the better option because it's usually best not to edit the source code of a plugin as when you update it with a newer version, you have to remember to alter the code....times that by several dozen sites and it could be a real effort!

Answer (score 0):

just set `preventDefaultEvents: false`

locally like

```
   $("#section-content").touchwipe({
   preventDefaultEvents: false ...
```

or globally like

```
   var config = {
   preventDefaultEvents: true ...
```